# Radio button value returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html, typescript, radio-button, undefined

The buttons are visible and working, however when submit is clicked It should assign the value of the checked radio button(for each of the 3groups) to a variable,but the value returned is always undefined.

I expect the output to be the value or an object containing the values due to a group of buttons

```js
severityFormValue.on("click", (e) => {
  const loggedVia = $('input[name=loggedVia]:checked').val()
  const allStable = $('input[name = allStable]:checked').val()
  const EnvDown = $('input[name = EnvDown]:checked').val()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="dropdown">
       <button class="dropbtn" id="CCR_DACEbtn">CCR DACE ▼</button>
       <div id="drowdownCCR_DACEID" class="dropdown-content">
               Submitted by:
               <input type="radio" name="loggedVia" value="phone" checked> phone
               <input type="radio" name="loggedVia" value="email"> email<br>
               All services stable?
               <input type="radio" name="allStable" value="Yes"> Yes 
               <input type="radio" name="allStable" value="No" checked> No 
               <input type="radio" name="allStable" value="N/A"> N/A <br>
               Environment Down?
               <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="Yes"> Yes 
               <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="No" checked> No 
               <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="N/A"> N/A <br>
               <button type="button" id="severityFormSubmit" >Submit</button>
       </div>
   </div>`
```

Comment: What is `severityFormValue`?

Comment: a variable assigned to the button severityFormSubmit

Comment: What if you do `$('input[name="loggedVia"]:checked').value`? Same for `allStable` and `envDown`.

Comment: @StephanSchrijver then you'll get `undefined` as jQuery objects don't have a `value` property

Comment: @StephanSchrijver Tried it before, no changes

Comment: Mr McCrossan I believe he meant to add quotes around the name, still it doesn't work.

Comment: Excuse me, was indeed also meaning the quotes but also mixed up JavaScript and jQuery I guess (was executing the line in the Developer Tools console). Also not able to reproduce the problem in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4td9g7z/1/, seems to work properly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the second group of radio inputs is `AllStable`, not `allStable`, hence the selector won't find them as it's case-sensitive. Fix that and the code you've shown works fine:

```js
var severityFormValue = $('#severityFormSubmit');

severityFormValue.on("click", (e) => {
  const loggedVia = $('input[name="LoggedVia"]:checked').val()
  const allStable = $('input[name="AllStable"]:checked').val();
  const envDown = $('input[name="EnvDown"]:checked').val()

  console.log(loggedVia);
  console.log(allStable);
  console.log(envDown);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" id="CCR_DACEbtn">CCR DACE ▼</button>
  <div id="drowdownCCR_DACEID" class="dropdown-content">
    Submitted by:
    <input type="radio" name="LoggedVia" value="phone" checked> phone
    <input type="radio" name="LoggedVia" value="email"> email<br> 
    
    All services stable?
    <input type="radio" name="AllStable" value="Yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="AllStable" value="No" checked> No
    <input type="radio" name="AllStable" value="N/A"> N/A <br> 
    
    Environment Down?
    <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="Yes"> Yes
    <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="No" checked> No
    <input type="radio" name="EnvDown" value="N/A"> N/A <br>
    <button type="button" id="severityFormSubmit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I changed the `EnvDown` variable name to `envDown` and the `loggedVia` name attribute to `LoggedVia` to maintain consistency with their counterpart values.

Comment: still returns undefined in the app, yes it is a major mistake i didn't notice, however the loggedVia should have worked ..

Comment: In which case can you please edit the question to include relevant code which recreates the problem.

Comment: There shouldn't be any other code impairing the return value of the radio button i think

Comment: Unfortunately, from the code you've shown in the question the answer above solves the issues you've shown, as you can see from the working snippet. If it's not working for you there must be some other underlying issue.

Comment: It is strange since values are directly assigned with the proper method ,yet even alerted they are undefined.When i remove the value and alert the input[]:checked it returns object object. so i was thinking - maybe since it is a group of radios it creates an object with more values than needed?

Comment: `maybe since it is a group of radios it creates an object with more values than needed?` That shouldn't be possible as you're selecting by name, and only 1 radio per named group can be selected. You can confirm this by logging `$('input[name="AllStable"]:checked').length`

Comment: I've udated adding the div parents ,although i still believe there should be no problem with that.The current html I've shown is getting appended through the typescript file and isn't a part of the html one

Comment: Thanks for editing. Even with that HTML the code should still work - as you can see from my updated answer. If you're dynamically appending content then that may be a problem, but I'd expect nothing at all to happen if the event handler wasn't bound, not `val()` being undefined.

Comment: Well thanks for your time none the less.I'll look for the problem somewhere in the app or the frame itself.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't solve it entirely. Hopefully this has at least given you something to go on.

Comment: so it turns out the .length method you mentioned earlier returns 0.Somehow the checked radios aren't found.....